Get unique objects from AJAX response
I am trying to get unique objects from an array of objects returned by an AJAX response. I found something similar here but I have one additional condition and not sure how to tackle it.
The partial code looks like:
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false, 
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("../WebService/ABC.asmx/GetSomething") %>',
    data: JSON.stringify({ StartDate: startDate, EndDate: endDate }),
}).done(function (result) {
    jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);
    uniqueLabels = [];    

    // This is from another SOF post
    // Get unique A records where B is 'H2'
    var a = jResult.filter((value, index, self) => {
        return self.findIndex(v => v.A === value.A && v.B == 'H2') === index;
    });  

However, there could be more than one records having the same A value and have B equal to H2 and I need to pick the latest one if that's the case (timestamp is C in each object).
The above does return the unique A records having B equal to 'H2' but not necessarily the latest one.
Sample jResult, first and third have same A and B values, different timestamps:
{
    "A": "037413172",
    "B": "H2",
    "C": "2024-04-08T08:45:13.989605",
    "D": "BE"
}
{
    "A": "037413172",
    "B": "NQ",
    "C": "2024-04-08T09:06:29.484146",
    "D": "BE"
}
{
    "A": "037413172",
    "B": "H2",
    "C": "2024-04-09T10:03:39.484296",
    "DEST_COUNTRY": "BE"
}
{
    "A": "216023781",
    "B": "NQ",
    "C": "2024-04-08T11:53:46.910811",
    "D": "AT"
}


Why not use JavaScript Object? And just compare (===) the properties to your liking.

Is the "ajax" part actually relevant to the question?  The issue only seems to be once you've got your array of objects.

Sort by C first (date descending so latest is first).   As findIndex (MDN) returns "first element in an array that [matches]" then by sorting them, the first in the array will be the latest one.

@fdomn-m you are correct. I just included it for completeness but it had nothing to do with how the array is obtained.

First you should filter by all the items that has the requested B. Then you should "group object by key having item.C the latest". I was fancy to use reduce but it's just about setting the value on the correct object keys. Finally we return the result which is the now unique values of the object.


function getUnique(arr, B) {
  var brr = arr.filter(item => item.B === B)
  var crr = brr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
    if (!agg[item.A] || agg[item.A].C <= item.C) {
      agg[item.A] = item
    }
    return agg
  }, {})
  var drr = Object.values(crr)
  return drr;

}

var arr = [{
    "A": "037413172",
    "B": "H2",
    "C": "2024-04-08T08:45:13.989605",
    "D": "BE"
  },
  {
    "A": "037413172",
    "B": "NQ",
    "C": "2024-04-08T09:06:29.484146",
    "D": "BE"
  },
  {
    "A": "037413172",
    "B": "H2",
    "C": "2024-04-09T10:03:39.484296",
    "DEST_COUNTRY": "BE"
  },
  {
    "A": "216023781",
    "B": "NQ",
    "C": "2024-04-08T11:53:46.910811",
    "D": "AT"
  }
]


console.log(getUnique(arr, "H2"))
console.log(getUnique(arr, "NQ"))
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%
}



